# Simple Html Dom Parser, как исключить class?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Парсинг страницы с помощью PHP Simple HTML Dom Parser:

```
<tr class="bull-item">
 Нужный элемент
</tr>

<tr data-dummy="extended_item" class="bull-item">
 Ненужный элемент
</tr>
```

Как исключить элементы с `data-dummy="extended_item"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$elements = $simple->find('tr');
foreach($elements as $value) {
    if(isset($value->{'data-dummy'}) && 'extended_item' === $value->{'data-dummy'}) {
        continue;
    }
}
```